# Centering Logo in Responsive site

Tags: css, responsive-design

I need that when the Wordpress responsive theme is resized, move the Logo image (initially in the left), to the center of its container.
This [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/2r9gsk/direct) is from the div container CSS. I can see how width is variable.

EDIT: I'm using the Bootstrap theme, so this live demo might help, http://demo.opencodez.com/openstrap/

Comment: Using `text-align: center;` ?

Comment: add a width and height to logo and dispaly as block. Then apply margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto when min-width of container is 992px or less.

Comment: Post your `HTML` and `CSS`, not just a screenshot.

Comment: I'm using the openstrap theme, so this live demo can help: http://demo.opencodez.com/openstrap/
In that case I would like to move the logo text to the center when I reached the "mobile version"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many ways to do that.
From the screenshot I can tell that your theme is using bootstrap and logo is placed within navbar (my guess) so you can see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

in case of top title:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .logo-row > div {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .logo-row .img-responsive {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! i've edit my post and added the theme live demo.
should i pay attention to the "col-md-4 pull-left" class? I'll try that in case navbar-brand is used.

Comment: does logo have those classes? (it does not have in on live version). anyways, if you are using second version suggested by me add logo has `pull-left` class, you should change float to `float: none !important;` since pull-left has !important rule.

Comment: Ok. I mean, the div container of the <h1> site title (in my case, a logo image) has a class called "col-md-4 pull-left". Just clicking the Inspector Debug on the logo

Comment: Now I see, I just updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, buy sorry, that moved the "home" icon in the navigation bar to the center.
I'd like to move the Logo Image or the Text logo to the center :/

Comment: You are applying wrong code. try the last one: `@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .logo-row > div {
        float: none !important;
        text-align: center;
    }
}`

Comment: Genius man, it worked. I should learn CSS from the start. I hate myself trying to modify those advanced stylings.

Comment: It works with text but makes a mess with logo image, don't know why. Don't care. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Its okay, we are all noobs here )) try describe your problem and I'll try to help. In original (live) version, img is hidden when width is less then 767px. What kind of mess it makes? How different your version is from live one? also dont forget to accept this as answer ;)

Comment: ok ;) this happens: http://prntscr.com/2radi2/direct
however I tried that code with the live version and it worked.

Comment: Its really hard to see from screenshot. Does it look normal without our styles applied? maybe you can screenshot your markup too. like this: http://prntscr.com/2rahlp

Comment: hah )) nice job. now I see the real problem. I updated my answer